# How to use both UARTs on Raspberry Pi 3 Compute module

Tags: hardware, raspberry-pi3

I am working on a project which has a Raspberry Pi 3 Compute Module integrated into a hardware design where the PCB provides access to both Serial Ports on the compute module:

- One serial port with TX/RX on GPIO 14/15 (pins 51/53 of module)
- One serial port with CTS/RTS/TX/RX on GPIO 31/31/32/33 (pins 34/36/46/48 of the module)

As far as I understand there is one full 16650 compatible UART available in the BCM2835 called the "PL011", and one mini-UART which is normally used to communicate with the internal BlueTooth chip.

When booting Raspbian Jesse, I see the `/dev/ttyAMA0` device which seems to communicate on GPIO pins 14/15, and according to what I have read this communication runs through the PL011 full UART chip. I have tried to create a `/boot/config.txt` file which has the following device tree overlays:

```
dtoverlay=uart1,txd1_pin=32,rxd1_pin=33
enable_uart=1
```

This does not seem to provide me with a `/dev/ttyAMA1` device. This seems consistent with the description in the `/boot/overlays/README` file which states:

```
Name: Uart1
Info: Enable uart1 in place of uart0
```

I did find a limited driver for the mini-UART which is fixed at 115200 baud, which seems like a driver to use the mini-UART instead of the full UART.

What I'd like to do is: without redesigning the hardware, configure the "PL011" full UART to use the CTS/RTS/TX/RX port, *and* the mini-UART to use the TX/RX port, so that I can use *both* serial ports in my application.